# Adding CCS, Javascripts and PHP files into Joomla websites

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, css, joomla

I am quite new to Joomla and have come across a problem that annoys me as a programmer alot!

Now Ive been watching several tutorials on-line and all of them state "Its so easy for non programmers to create a website with Joomla"

While that's fine and all there seem to be few tutorials that actually show what "powers" you do have if you infact have programmering experience.

Here is my problem:

I want to be able to add PHP, Javascripts CSS and HTML to my site i have stumbled across JUMI but as far as i know it only allows me to add scripts to articles and modules.

Here is an example of what i want to achieve:

I will buy and use a template at [Themeforest](http://themeforest.net/) Then i want to create a search bar using HTML and PHP, when using the search option the site will run my script and load the result into a table using a combination of JQuery and HTML.

Other than that i wish to create a session so that when user for example tries to purches items on my site will be saved and so that my site actually remembers the users choices.

Now i do not except you guys to have all the answers but a simple redirect to a tutorial, paper or any other place where i can learn about how to make this work would make me very gratefull.

**Question update**

So i think my question is abit hard to understand i ive made this update:

Maybe i have misunderstood some things but say for instance one of you guys download a template how do you go on from there? how do you manipulate the modules so that when you search for something the search is done in another database table than the default one? how do you create a login for users to use and add your own costum scripts?

These are only a few examples but i hope you get the idea.

Comment: It is very easy for non programmers to create a website using Joomla. Have a look T the Joomla Extensions Directory, look for extensions that suit your needs and test them. Also have a look at the Joomla documentation and start experimenting with a few things.

Comment: I know its rather easy to create a website but i am a programmer and i want to change some functionalities

Comment: Make a copy of the template in the template manager. Then edit away (but you need to  upload new files. IF the extensions you are using don't support the two core search options you can make a plugin for them, instructions on the wiki. All core tables are already covered by search.  Login is built in but you can add a profile plugin and others that take advantage of the  joomla event system.    But you do want to write these using the Joomla APIs.

Comment: I think for most things you won't need to change functionalities at all. You just need to learn how to use Joomla. Like Elin said, you can change your template in the template manager, you can add your search bar as a module, if you don't like the standard modules you can download more of them. No reason to use Joomla if you want to reinvent the wheel, otherwise you should probably just use some kind of framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read more abou Joomla modules. They allow to add bits of your own custom functionality to your websites :

http://docs.joomla.org/Module

[update]

If you need to create more self-contained bits of functionalites that operate on their own db tables ect then you most likely need to build component (the tutorial below is quite hands-on):

http://docs.joomla.org/J2.5:Developing_a_MVC_Component/Developing_a_Basic_Component

I realize the Joomla docs are not great. I myself learned most by studying code of core templates and components

Comment: Thank you for your response but i cant seem to find the "Place" where it actually shows how to modify modules?

Comment: Ive updated my post abit if you have time please have a look :)

Comment: Don't modify, make a copy and change the copy, then do discover install. But often you don't need to change anything, just set some options.  Of course it's great to code your own as well but don't reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 1):

Search bar is a full integrated feature to frameworks like

```
Joomla
Drupal
Wordpress
```

and so on..

If you want sessions and some more advanced security mechanism you might want to think about buying a ssl certificate and do most of the interaction to the server by SSL encryption.

Also you sholud look at:

http://www.opencart.org

is that answer your problem?

Comment: Not really, i need to know how i can manipulate them? searching the site for an item is not the same as searching a database full of a specefic item

Comment: opencart is your answer. its really amazing and do exactly as you asked.

Comment: Marc, You really just have to read the Joomla development documentaton. Joomla is totally OOP so everything is overridable or you can create your own modules, plugins, components and templates.  I think  you are probably thinking that things are harder than they are. If you want a new module just follow the patterns in a core example.  Also the book Joomla! Programming might help you.
For search that's built in you don't need to do anything but design  the look and set the options.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are working on a joomla 2.5. I don't know if you are able to build a new template (copy of Themeforest) and override that.

For the adds you got many solutions. You can override your template, build modules or componments that you gonna put in different postion, or you can try some plugin like sourcerer, module anywhere...All that depends on the type of your site, sometimes that doesn't feet.

For the session I think you still have several choices, build it from scratch or search for a module.

Hope that helps.

I would create a module. I'm sure there are several ways to do that but that's what I would do. From scratch or with blank_module (joomla module).

You got some doc here : http://docs.joomla.org/J2.5:Creating_a_simple_module/Developing_a_Basic_Module

Here for the output ovveride (other database for example) : http://docs.joomla.org/Understanding_Output_Overrides